# undefined method `send_data' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip, download

I am trying to download the data stored amazon s3 bucket using paperclip and aws-sdk gem. Object is publicly accessible.

I am having a method in my controller where I intend do download the data directly.

```
def method_where_downloading_happens
  code for finding url from params
  send_file "ModelName.attached_file.url"
end
```

`#Tried both with static and dynamic url.`

I am getting following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `send_file for main:Object
```

However if I use :-

```
send_file open(ModelName.attached_file.url)
```

Then a file is downloaded but it's format is binary i.e. windows can't identify the file_type.

Please help how do I provide direct download when the person hits the link.

Comment: Which rails version do you use? As `send_data` in `ActionController::Streaming` is moved to `AC::DataStreaming` in Rails v3.0.9 || [Link to apidock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data)

Comment: Where you are writing  the code for downloading a file?

Comment: @Kers I am using rails 3.2.9 and ruby 1.9.3,

Comment: @RAJ...I am writing this in the method where I wish the user to come for downloading the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
#In your environment.rb require 'open-uri'
require 'open-uri'

#As send_data will work in controller, so in your controller
def index
  data = open(params[:file])
  send_data data, :filename => params[:name], ...
end
```

Comment: `require 'open-uri'` returns 
`false`
 still after adding it in environment.rb

Comment: If you are running `require 'open-uri'` from console and its returning `false`, it means `'open-uri'` was already included into application. So, no need to worry